# Give mat-table a height and make mat-row scrollable

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a mat-table:

```
 <div class="card-body">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="filteredEntries">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Date</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let dailyEntry">{{dailyEntry.date | date:'shortDate'}}</td>
      </ng-container>
      // more columns...
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:displayedColumns;"
          [class.cal-day-selected]="row.date.isSame(selectedDay)"
          [class.highlighted-daily-entry]="row === highlightedDailyEntry"
          [class.highlight-selected]="dailyEntriesActionQueue.includes(row) && inBackoffice"
          (click)="onRowClick($event, row)"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

I would like to give the table(or the mat-row) a height and make the `mat-row` scrollable if needed. But the problem is that height doesnt have any effect on both the `mat-table` and the `mat-row`. Im able to do it by adding a wrapper class `card-body`:

```
.card-body {
  height: 80vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

But that obviously adds a scrollbar to the entire table, not just the `mat-row`. Applying `overflow-y` and/or `height` to the `mat-row` doesnt do anything. Does anyone have an idea how to add a height to a table and make only the `mat-row` scrollable if it exceeds the height?

**Edit:**
Im basically getting it to work exactly like in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ndomlrqbkpp?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sticky-header-example.html) posted in the comments. Thats working fine, but instead of the scrollbar starting from the very top of the table, i would like it to start after the header.

So instead of this(starting at the top of the table) [image: currently]

i would like it to look like this(starting after the header, black bar is representing the scrollbar)

[image: second]

Comment: You are doing fine as far as it look in https://stackblitz.com/angular/ndomlrqbkpp?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sticky-header-example.html but can you make your code example on `stackblitz`

Comment: Yes, i get it to work like in the stackblitz you posted. I edited my original post to visualize what i want to achieve.

Comment: I have made a few modifications that do what you are searching for. But seems to be a little dirty. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-biihxm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that with the current material table implementation.
However, you can quite easily - but not so elegantly - resolve that by moving the header row element from the table into the wrapping element above:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const headerRow = document.querySelector('mat-header-row');
    const matTable = document.querySelector('mat-table');
    const tableContainer = document.querySelector('.example-container');
    if (tableContainer && headerRow && matTable) {
      tableContainer.insertBefore(headerRow, matTable);
    }
  }
```

Then you set the wrapper's overflow to hidden and the table's height to 100% and overflow to auto in your CSS file. I also changed to flex layout for the wrapper:

```
.example-container {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

mat-table {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Please note, I also changed to using the material table elements instead of attributes, it frees you from using the html table element.

See a working example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnale6

Answer (score -2):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: You will need to explain why you claim this to be the solution.

Comment: it just makes the scroller start 50px lower

Comment: Max you need to explain it inside your answer.